# href attribute value not working in Python Flask app for target HTML pages

Tags: python, flask

I have a basic flask application with the following structure:

app.py

templates/index.html

static/js/common.js

static/css/common.css

In the top navigation bar of my index.html file, I want to have menu buttons contain links to other HTML pages. However, when I tried various ways of specifying the target html files in href attribute of a tags, it doesn't work. On click, the page fails to load.
What is the correct and quick way of mentioning target HTML files/path in my index.html?

```
    <body>
        <div class="navbar-header">
             <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand"><strong>My Website</strong></a> 
        </div>
    </body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The template (index.html) needs to be rendered by a route in your Flask application.

To render the index.html template with the URL /index.html:

```
@app.route('/index.html')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html')
```

Refer to this section in the quickstart guide:
http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/quickstart/#rendering-templates

It's probably worth reading through the whole guide at the same time. As a side note, it's unconventional to include .html extensions in your URLs in Flask, but it's your call.